# Expanding Spinner Items

Tags: android, spinner

I'm currently implementing a Spinner in Android and having trouble getting two arrays linked with the Spinner- one for when the spinner is not expanded, and one for when it is.

So the spinner would look like this when it is not expanded:
[image: Small Spinner]

And when it is expanded the array linked to it changes from the shortened version of the strings to the long versions. 
[image: Expanded Spinner]

I've thought about changing the array when the Spinner is touched, and then changing it back when it's cancelled but I think this will end up being messy, or otherwise creating a button that looks like a spinner, which opens up a custom ListView dialog to act as a custom Spinner, but this seems like overkill. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own adapter to achieve this effect.  Override the getView() returning your "expanded" view, and getDropDownView() returning your "collapsed" view.  Don't forget to take advantage of the convertView.

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 0, objects) {
        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //inflate and return the view you want to see as the non-expanded droplist
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //inflate and return the expanded view
        }
    };
```